# Graph of continuous function has zero Jordan measure

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

> Show that the graph $\{(x,f(x)): x \in B \} \subset \mathbb{R}^{d+1}$ has  Jordan measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$.

**My approach:**
Since $f$ is continuous it is Riemann integrable over $B$ which gives an immediate cover of the graph $G$ of $f$:
By definition, for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists some partition of $B$ into  cuboids $Q_{1}, \ldots, 
Q_{n}$ s.t. $U( f, \mathcal{P} ) - L( f, \mathcal{P} )< \epsilon $. This gives us the cover
(writing $l(f, Q) = \inf_{ x \in Q} f( x)$ and $u(f, Q) = \sup_{ x \in Q} f( x)$)
\begin{aligned}
G \subset \underbrace{\bigcup_{k = 1}^{n} 
 Q_{k}\times \left[ l( f, Q_{k}), u( f, Q_{k})\right]}_{\mathcal{C}}
\end{aligned}
whereby
\begin{aligned}
m( G)\le  m\left( \mathcal{C}\right) 
= \sum_{k = 1}^{n} m( Q_{k}) ( u( f, Q_{k}) - l( f, Q_{k}))
= U( f, \mathcal{P} ) - L( f, \mathcal{P} )< \epsilon 
.\end{aligned}

Does my approach work?

Comment: Yep! This is a slick way of proving it. My only suggestion would be to replace $m(G)$ with $m^*(G)$, the outer measure of $G$. Then, since $m^*(G) = 0$, we have $m_*(G) = 0$, and we end up proving $G$ is Jordan measurable, not just computing the Jordan measure.

Comment: @TheoBendit thanks!